# Unable to use gpu in azure windows server 2016

Tags: azure, windows-server-2016, nvidia, gpu

I am trying to run a GPU intensive application(Lumion) on the Azure cloud.

Image used - **Windows Server 2016.**

Hardware - **NV6_Promo** with 1xK80 GPU.

Any application, when launched, run without using the GPU. The system has the latest Nvidia Tesla drivers and DirectX installed.

What I understood after researching

- Need to enable "Use the hardware default graphics adapter for all Remote Desktop Services sessions" in **group policy**.
- Need to use Virtual Machine like **Hyper-V** to enable hardware acceleration

Enabling graphics adapter in **group policy didn't solve my problem**. Installed Hyper-V; however, **Hyper-V doesn't show the GPU**. The GPU shows up in Device manager and running 'Nvidia-msi' also shows that it is not being used by any application.

How can I enable hardware acceleration on Azure cloud GPU machines?

Answer (score 3):

After searching for 3 days, I finally found the solution from some gaming forum.

Procedure to enable GPU on Windows-based Cloud System

1. Download Nvidia Driver from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/n-series-driver-setup)
2. Install DirectX [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35)
3. Open Device Manager
4. Expand Display Adapters - Two adapters will be listed: Microsoft Hyper-V Virtual & Nvidia Tesla K80(can be different depending on selected series)
5. Disable Microsoft Hyper-V Virtual
6. Run CMD as administrator. Go to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI folder, and run nvidia-smi.This will get you a table that gives you what mode your Tesla is set to (which will be TCC by default, check under the heading TCC/WDDM), and the GPU_ID, which is the thing under the Bus-Id heading.
7. Run nvidia-smi -g {GPU_ID} -dm {0|1} with your Bus-Id and 0 to set it to WDDM, like so:`nvidia-smi -g 0001:00:00.0 -dm 0` . More [info](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/nsight/tesla_compute_cluster.htm)
8. Reboot the system and you are done
9. Use this nvidia [demo](https://www.nvidia.com/coolstuff/demos#!/lifelike-human-face-rendering) to test performance